# How to handle multiple distance matrix api request in loop to reduce load and request time?

Tags: google-maps

```
if ($query->have_posts()) : 
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

 $school_address =str_replace(' ','+',$school_address );

     $school_address =str_replace(',','',$school_address);

      $zipcodeaddress =str_replace(' ','+',$zipcodeaddress );

     $zipcodeaddress =str_replace(',','',$zipcodeaddress);


    $fare = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins='.$school_address.'&destinations='.$zipcodeaddress.'&key=KEY');
//here im making api request in loop which is taking to long to load 
// what will be the best solution to calculate the distnace in loop.... correcponting to ther office address

    $data = json_decode($fare);
    $data = (array)$data;

    $result = (array)$data['rows']['0'];
    $result = (array)$result['elements']['0'];

    $distance = (array)$result['distance'];
    $duration = (array)$result['duration'];

    $distance = str_replace('mi', '', $distance);
endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Not sure what is the question here, and how is it wordpress specific. If you need to calculate something at request time, and request may vary, than you can not do any sort of caching which is usually the solution for such things.

Comment: Thanks for your comment... after a lot of struggle i got the solution...

Answer (score 0):

```
I need to pass the lat and long for two address
```

function calculate_distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

```
  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  $unit = strtoupper($unit);

  if ($unit == "K") {
    return ($miles * 1.609344);
  } else if ($unit == "N") {
      return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else {
        return $miles;
      }
}

echo calculate_distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "M") . " Miles<br>";
```